# Navigation controller in landscape, pop scrolls up

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, landscape

my app use a navigation controller and i'm trying to insert the landscape support!
I have my NavigationController and a view, that is called with an IBAction (connected at a UIButton) with this code:

```
view *myview = [[view alloc] initWithNibName:@"view" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self pushViewController:myview animated:YES];
```

Of course, i've imported "myview.h" in my NavigationController_Class

So, for the landscape, i've inserted this code in "myview.m" and in "NavigationController_Class.m"

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
 }
```

What's the problem? 
It works, but when you touch the button for the pop of the view from the stack, this scrolls not from the right to the left, but from up to down!

Do you know what could be the problem?
thanks!

Comment: You really should return YES in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: - method, since you are supporting all four orientations.

Comment: ok, right, thanks! But the problem isn't solved, nothing changed! The navigationControlles still scrolls up

Answer (score 3):

im guessing you have a `UINavigationController` inside a `UITabBarController`?

the solution is to override the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of each view controller in a navigation stack (the last one is not necessary) and return `YES` for supported Orientations